# Automating changes to RabbitMQ config

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have a project using Spring Integration + RabbitMQ.  We're still in early development, so we're rapidly changing the topology of our integration architecture, including the RabbitMQ configuration.

We're also trying to follow continuous deployment, with a hands-free deployment.

I have a `<rabbit:admin />` element declared in my spring config, which nicely takes care of adding new exchanges or queues.

However, I find that it fails when I'm deploying an update that changes the configuration of an existing exchange / queue.

Recently, a couple of deployments have failed because:

- We switched out a Direct Queue to a FanOut exchange
- We changed the declared TTL for messages on a direct queue.

In both instances, there was a change required to existing configuration, instead of just creating a new instance.  These updates weren't applied, causing startup to fail.

For both, the fix was simple - delete the offending resources, restart the app, and `<rabbit:admin />` kicks in a replaces them with the correct definition.

However, in a production system, we can't be doing that.  Also, that's not currently scripted as part of our deployment, making continual deployment more cumbersome.

What tools or strategies are available for a continual deployment strategy that can handle updates to a RabbitMQ topology?

Answer (score 1):

A way I've heard of doing it is to just create a new exchange and add new bindings to the existing queue. In this case you can move over the publishers to the next exchange and the consumers just consume from the same queue. Once everyone moves over you can drop the old queue, possibly with recreating and moving back to the previous name.

With queue changes this is more difficult as you will likely get duplicate messages if you create a new queue with the new settings and bind to the same exchanges. If this is done in concert with a new exchange (with the same config as the existing one) then you can prevent duplicate messages.

For any critical systems that can't sustain a deleted queue I'm more in favor of making a new cluster and moving all clients over to the new, correctly configured cluster. Instead of making a new cluster you could split up the existing cluster and fix one node, wipe the old one, and join it to the new node.

I've taken to managing exchange/queue configurations in Chef so that this process is a bit easier, there is no need to be careful about the order in which publishers and consumers connect to new nodes.

Those are the best I've seen/heard of. Backwards incompatible AMQP changes are similar to DB migrations in that regard. Adding compatible changes is easy to automate but incompatible changes require some care.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming 1.2 release (currently at milestone 1 - `1.2.0.M1`) now has [an option](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-amqp/pull/85) on the `RabbitAdmin` to log configuration problems (instead of failing to initialize) `ignore-declaration-exceptions`.

It won't change the existing configuration, but it will allow the application to initialize while logging warnings.

Comment: Thanks - that's certainly helpful, but I'm still curious how people manage this stuff?  I can't be the only one out there trying to do continuous deployment with RabbitMQ.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you ask the Rabbit experts on their list https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss